# How to insert unescaped text in Elixir Temple template?

Tags: elixir, temple

I'm experimenting with [Temple](https://github.com/mhanberg/temple) elixir library and have some troubles with escaped values.

Basically I have some text that I don't want to be escaped, just added in it's raw state.

So for example in my controller:

```
conn
  |> assign(:scripts_js, "alert('ok')")
```

and then in the template I do:

```
script do
  text @scripts_js
end
```

Howere the result of that is:

```html
<script>alert(&#39;ok&#39;)</script>
```

I've also tried with `partial`:

```
script do
  partial @scripts_js
end
```

but the result is also escaped.

How can I insert unescaped text in Temple's templates? Should I use a custom component for that or the library supports it somehow?

NOTE: Here the javascript is just an example. I'm not looking for an answer on how to insert a JS into a page (script tag with src attr would work just fine). What I need to know is to to insert an unescaped string, it may be JS, CSS, HTML or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked this question directly in [Temple github issues](https://github.com/mhanberg/temple/issues/10) and got an answer from @mhanberg.
So basically to put an unescaped text in the template we should use this:

```
partial Phoenix.HTML.raw("<div>Unescaped content!</div>")
# alternative approach, since all Phoenix.HTML.raw does is mark it as :safe
partial {:safe, "<div>Unescaped content!</div>"}
```

So to answer the initial question the correct structure would be:

```
script do
  partial Phoenix.HTML.raw(@scripts_js)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your js in a file, then in your template use:

```
script type: "text/javascript", src: @js_path
```

In the action in your controller, you would write:

```
  def my(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, 
      "my.html",   #template
      js_path: Routes.static_path(conn, "/js/my.js")  #path to js file
    )
  end
```

At the bottom of `js/app.js` you would write:

```
import "./my.js"
```

then create the file `js/my.js` with the content:

```
alert("ok");
```

The problem your having is because Temple's `text()` function/macro calls `Phoenix.HTML.html_escape()` on the string.  Unfortunately, `text()` returns `:ok`, not the actual text, otherwise you could just pipe the return value of `text()` through something like `HmtlEntities.decode()` to get the raw string back.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question. Here you are just showing how to import a js file to the template via <script src="..."/> which is quite obvious. What I need to know is how to insert AN UNESCAPED text in Temple's template. Here the javascript is just an example. I'm also quite aware why Temple's text() function does the escaping, I've read it's code before posting the question.

Comment: *I've read it's code*  -- Then it should be *quite obvious* what the answer is.

Comment: I've read the code of "text" and "partial" functions and briefly browsed trough the rest of the source code however still couldn't find anything. But maybe I've missed something because that's quite strange that a template library allow you only to escape variables. That's why I'm asking.